# Do plans exist to add a Earth 3D View map type to the Google Maps API?

Tags: 3d, maps, cesiumjs

I'd like to develop and google maps application which defaults to a 3D Earth view, similar to the Cesium API.  Are there plans for a future google maps API release, v4,  to include a 3D earth/global view?

Answer (score 0):

In maps.google.com currently, if you switch to "Earth" view by clicking the box in the lower-left, and then zoom out a lot, you can see [a view that looks like a 3D Earth](https://www.google.com/maps/@31.4082444,-83.0606219,10899142m/data=!3m1!1e3).  When zoomed in, hold the CTRL key and left-drag to pan and tilt the camera in 3D.  I don't know if this same view is already available via the API, but it may just be a matter of switching out of map mode and zooming out.

Currently I don't know of any way to show just the road maps on a Google Earth 3D globe, similar to what Cesium can do.